# Error creating python backend for Next.js application

Tags: python, next.js

I'm trying to run an AI model that I previously trained on the backend of a next.js application. The model is in a .joblib file and the way the app works is: there's a form that the user fills, then there a `handleSubmit` function that looks like this:

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/api/adult/predict', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error making prediction:', error);
        }
    };
```

And my Python backend looks like this:

```
@app.route('/api/adult/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predictAdult():
    print('heyyyy, I ran')
    # Load the model
    this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    joblib_path = os.path.join(this_dir, 'adult.joblib')
    sys.path.append(this_dir)
    model = joblib.load(joblib_path)

    # Check if the request contains JSON data
    if request.is_json:
        # Parse JSON data from the request body
        data = request.get_json()

        # Ensure the JSON data contains the expected keys
        if True:
            # Perform prediction with the loaded model
            # Assuming the model expects data in the form of a list of dictionaries
            for key in data:
                data[key] = processesData(key, data[key])
            print('processed data:', data)


            prediction_data = pd.DataFrame([data], index=[0])  # Specify the index explicitly
            prediction = model.predict_proba(prediction_data)[0][1]
            pred = round(prediction*100)

            return str(pred)
```

It works perfectly on local host, but it does not work on Vercel, any ideas on how to fix it?

I tried changing from axios to fetch, both of which work on my computer, but none worked on Vercel, I always get this error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()